# File Validation in multer

Tags: node.js, validation, mime-types, multer

I want to validate the mime-type before uploding it with multer to my server. Currently I'm uploading it and deleting if it has not the correct magic number.

I did the test, with multer filter it's possible to change the extension and the mime validation fails. So I started to use [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) package that matches the magic number and now the tests works perfectly. The problem is I can't integrate [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) validation in multer filters, because the `req.file` argument dissapears and the `file` it's only information it extracts from the file (without magic number validation) so I can't access the file to use file-type

```
/////////////////////
// fileHandler.js  //
/////////////////////

const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');

const image_allowed_extensions = /(jpg|png|tiff|gif|jpeg)$/;

/**
 * returns a multer instance with diskStorage
 * only accepts the files that match {@link image_allowed_extensions}
 * @type {multer}
 */
const MulterImageInstance = multer({
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5_000_000, // 5 MB MAX
        files: 1
    },
    fileFilter: async (req, file, cb) => {
        if(!image_allowed_extensions.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase()))
            return cb(new Error('Error: not supported extension'));
        if(!image_allowed_extensions.test(file.mimetype))
            return cb(new Error('Error: invalid mimetype'));
        return cb(null, true);
    },
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, callback) => {
            const dir = path.join(__dirname, "../../files/private/images");
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir))
                fs.mkdirSync(dir);
            callback(null, dir)
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            const file_name = `${new Date().getTime()}-${uuidV4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
            callback(null, file_name);
        }
    })
});
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { MulterImageInstance } = require("../fileHandler");
const fileType = require('file-type');

router.post(/^\/register-user$/, MulterImageInstance.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

    if (req.file) {
        const mime = await fileType.fromFile(req.file.path);
        if(!/(jpg|png|tiff|gif|jpeg)$/.test(mime.mime)) {
            fs.unlink(req.file.path, err => {
                logger.errors.error(err);
            });
            return res.status(422).end();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are not getting req.file in filter ? Because the 1st code snippet looks fine to me and didn't get your question

Comment: Exactly, `req.file` is undefined in fileFilter